# Delete row if no foreign references, or update otherwise

Tags: sql, sql-update, db2, delete-row

I have a DB2 database with three tables:  `locations`, `items`, `movement_history`.  The `items` table has a foreign key, `location_id`, into `locations`.  The `movement_history` table has a foreign key, `item_id`, into `items`, and two foreign keys, `location_id_before` and `location_id_after`, into `locations`.

I want to delete a `location` if no row in `items` or `movement_history` references it.  If the `location` row *is* referenced somewhere, I just want to update it to be marked as deleted.  Is there a way to do this in one statement?  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: SQL statements let you do one thing at at time: SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT or DELETE. What you want to do is an UPDATE and DELETE within a single statement - I don't think that is possile.

Comment: I was hoping for something akin to DB2's `MERGE INTO ... WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE ... WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ...` query, but for delete/update instead of update/insert.

Comment: ...Actually, I wonder if I can use the `MERGE INTO` syntax with delete/update.  I'll look into that.

Comment: I think you may have just answered your own question. Both UPDATE and DELETE are valid actions for WHEN (I didn't know this either until I looked it up just now).

Answer (score 1):

Try command like this:

```
MERGE INTO LOCATIONS AS LOC
USING (
  SELECT Q1.ID, COALESCE(Q4.LOCATION_AFTER, Q3.LOCATION_BEFORE, Q2.LOCATION) AS ANY_REF
  FROM LOCATIONS Q1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ITEMS Q2 ON Q2.LOCATION = Q1.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MOVEMENT_HISTORY Q3 ON Q3.LOCATION_BEFORE = Q1.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MOVEMENT_HISTORY Q4 ON Q4.LOCATION_AFTER = Q1.ID) AS T1
    ON LOC.ID = T1.ID
WHEN MATCHED AND T1.ANY_REF IS NOT NULL THEN
  UPDATE SET ACTUAL = 'N'
WHEN MATCHED AND T1.ANY_REF IS NULL THEN
  DELETE
```